# ActiveRecord Query method: group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have read the Ruby docs on the query method "group", but I am having a hard time understanding how to use it.

lets say I have a table called users, and there are the fields name, email, gender.

I am able to type User.group(:name).count, which return a a hash with key value pairs of {name: count}.

Why does User.group(:name) not work?

Is there a way of grouping similar names, and accessing those records?
ex. User.group(:name).first or User.group(:name).each

It seems to me that I am thinking of using "group" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does User.group(:name) not work?

When you are using `GROUP BY` in SQL it needs a `SELECT` clause too. But it was absent in your case, and that throws error.

In your first case the query was `SELECT COUNT(*) from users GROUP BY name`, and this is the reason it worked.

As per your last sentence you need:

```
User.group(:name).select(:name).each do |record|
  # work with record
end
```

I don't know what is the DB client you are using, but here is the idea from Postgresql [GROUP BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) documentation.

> `GROUP BY` will condense into a single row all selected rows that share the same values for the grouped expressions. expression can be an input column name, or the name or ordinal number of an output column (`SELECT` list item), or an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values. In case of ambiguity, a `GROUP BY` name will be interpreted as an input-column name rather than an output column name.
>
> *Aggregate* functions, if any are used, are computed across all rows making up each group, producing a separate value for each group (whereas without GROUP BY, an aggregate produces a single value computed across all the selected rows). When `GROUP BY` is present, it is not valid for the `SELECT` list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions, since there would be more than one possible value to return for an *ungrouped* column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the method is starting to make much more sense to me. So basically, group does a select, but makes the record distinct per argument passed in?